# Ng2-Bootstrap : Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: angular2-directives, ng2-bootstrap

New to Angular2, and I'm trying to follow steps to implement ng2-bootstrap directives without success.
I'm getting this weird, time wasting error "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

My index.html file looks like

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/styles/roboto.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/styles/app.custom.css">   
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/styles/bootstrap-theme.min.css" > 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/styles/bootstrap.min.css" > 

  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
  <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script> 

  <script src="node_modules/ng2-pagination/dist/ng2-pagination-bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap.js"></script>

  <script> 

    System.config({
      packages: {
        app: {
          format: 'register',
          defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
      },
      map: {
        moment: 'node_modules/moment/moment.js'
      }
    });

    System.import('app/main').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });

  </script> 
</head>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: did you fix it?